# API Manager 2.0.0

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager, api-manager

Does anyone have API Manager 2.0.0 in a cluster in production. In other words you have it split running store, publisher, gateway, keymanager and trafficmanager each on at least one separate machine.

I am trying to setup two each, following the instructions here: https://docs.wso2.com/display/CLUSTER44x/Clustering+API+Manager+2.0.0

I have logged an issue on stackoverflow with regards to this and I have two other issues I cannot resolve. I have read every document on Carbon clustering, wso2 esb clustering and wso2am 1,9.0 and 2.0.0 and I am not makeing any progress.

OR

Does anyone have 1.9.0 running in a cluster?

Regards
Andre

Comment: What are the problems you're facing?

Comment: The ones logged on this blog that have not been answered for weeks now. i.e. remote registry mount unknown user error.

Comment: a link please...?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40758242/userregistry-attempted-to-authenticate-invalid-user

Comment: You shouldn't "bump" your questions like this.